# Rails, PostgreSQL, Heroku - how to change the ":null => false" rule?

Tags: validation, heroku, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1

I am working on my app (Rails 3.2, PostgreSQL 9.1) on localhost and everything works me well there, so I decided to deploy the app to the production to Heroku.

After successful deployment of the app I tried to create a new item and got this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "persistence_token" violates not-null constraint
```

It's about the table `Users` (use `Authlogic` gem). This is the sample of migration - critical part:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     create_table :users do |t|
       t.string    :name,                :null => false   
       t.string    :email,               :null => false                                           
       t.string    :crypted_password,    :default => nil, :null => true             
       t.string    :password_salt,       :default => nil, :null => true          
       t.string    :email,               :default => nil, :null => true          
       t.string    :persistence_token,   :null => false      
       t.string    :single_access_token, :null => false              
       t.string    :perishable_token,    :null => false            
       t.datetime  :last_request_at                                    
       t.datetime  :current_login_at                                   
       t.datetime  :last_login_at                                      
       t.string    :current_login_ip                                   
       t.string    :last_login_ip                                      

       t.timestamps
     end
   end
end
```

What could caused this problem? I mean, I see in the migration is the rule `:null => false` and the error message says about the null value saved into this column, but how is possible on localhost this work well and on Heroku not?

And, how could I fix that? My first idea was to create a new migration, where I set up for that column `:null => true`, but is it correct?

Comment: Setting `:null => true` just allows `null` values in the column, shadowing the original problem and opening a can of worms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the default value to `DEFAULT ''` and the error is gone...